# Casting Failed with Parse

Tags: objective-c, swift, parse-platform

I am using parse to do a tableviewer.  I am trying to load the table lines.  The error shows like below.

```
libswiftCore.dylib`swift_dynamicCastObjCClassUnconditional:
0x103710991:  je     0x1037109ac               ; swift_dynamicCastObjCClassUnconditional + 44
0x103710993:  movq   0x7f236(%rip), %rsi       ; "isKindOfClass:"
0x1037109a0:  callq  0x10371346a               ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x1037109aa:  je     0x1037109b3               ; swift_dynamicCastObjCClassUnconditional + 51
0x1037109b3:  leaq   0xc158(%rip), %rax        ; "Swift dynamic cast failed"
0x1037109ba:  movq   %rax, 0x87427(%rip)       ; gCRAnnotations + 8
```

My code line is :

```
        let array:NSArray = self.cartoonData.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects
        self.cartoonData = array as NSMutableArray
```

I think this is the error line code. But I don't know how can I fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the error speaks by itself:

```
Swift dynamic cast failed
```

which I interpret as: `array` cannot be cast to `NSMutableArray`. You should create a mutable copy of it:

```
self.cartoonData = NSMutableArray(array: array)
```

Comment: Now I receive an error on :fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented: file What should I do?

Comment: Hard to say without the code - you should provide more details. However that looks like a different problem, so it would probably be a good idea to create a new question